# The new careers profile editor makes me out to be an overachiever

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, profile-page

Previously, I had 205/210 points in my "profile completeness" level.

With the new design, suddenly this equates to 102%:
[image: Profile editor sidebar]

Is this intentional, e.g. to make sure that everybody always gives 110%?

Answer (score 4):

This should be resolved and getting over 100% completion isn't possible anymore. Though personally, you'll always be 102% in my heart.